# HashMap to Json Array Object - Java

Tags: java, json, loops, hashmap

I have a HashMap which I need to parse into JSON:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> worders = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to parse it into a JSON array of objects. **Current values:**

```
{"and": 100},
{"the": 50}
```

**Needed JSON format:**

```
[
{"word": "and",
"count": 100},
{"word": "the",
"count": 50}
]
```

I have realised that I need to use a loop to put it into the correct format, but not sure where or how to start.

I have also used the ObjectMapper() to write it as JSON, however, that does not correct the format, thank for help.

Comment: So you want to create a WordWithCount class, and populate a  List<WordWithCount> with what your HashMap contains, right? HashMap has an entrySet() method, which is a set of all its entries. So you can loop over if and transform each entry into a WordWithCount. Read the javadoc. try something.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do here.  Are you attempting to print out the JSON formatted values to the console, or store them in a data structure, or perhaps a file?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a formal Java class to do this.  We can try creating an `ArrayNode`, and then adding child `JsonNode` objects which represent each entry in your original hash map.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> worders = new HashMap<>();
worders.put("and", 100);
worders.put("the", 50);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode rootNode = mapper.createArrayNode();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : worders.entrySet()) {
    JsonNode childNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) childNode).put("word", entry.getKey());
    ((ObjectNode) childNode).put("count", entry.getValue());
    ((ArrayNode) rootNode).add(childNode);
}

String jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for!